# HttpWebRequest not downloading file correctly

Tags: c#, character-encoding, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I can't use `WebClient`, before anyone suggests that because it makes my legit application seem like a virus to McAfee. So please don't suggest that.

I have a binary.txt file stored on my server. It is approximately 1,240kb. However, HttpWebRequest downloads random amounts from 1,300kb to 1,700kb.

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create("http://deviantsmc.com/binary.txt");
httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
Stream httpResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1240];
int bytesRead = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

//FileStream fileStream = File.Create(@"tcontent.txt");
while ((bytesRead = httpResponseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1240)) != 0)
{
    sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
    //fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
File.WriteAllText(@"tcontent1.txt", sb.ToString());
```

(The contents of the binary.txt file on the server are in ASCII, therefore I get the Encoding string to ASCII as well).

This is how I encoded that text file (on that server)

My file is basically this:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("binary.txt");
String encBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
File.WriteAllText(file("binary.txt"), encBytes);
```

I contacted the AV company about the `WebDownloader` being seen as some malicious import in C#, but they didn't get back to me, so I'm forced to use `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: I download the file in browser, but it  does not look like ANSI encoded.

Comment: I've posted up how I encode my bytes of that text file.

Comment: So you are reading binary.txt as ASCII and then write the string back to the same file, right? What is the value of `encBytes` in debugger, is it a readable string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your only goal is to fetch that binary and write it to disk you can simply copy the stream to a file with the [`CopyTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx) method that exists on a [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

Your file looks like a broken zip file btw, given the first characters that are `PK`, and is used in the zip specificaton.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)):

> Viewed as an ASCII string this reads "PK", the initials of the inventor Phil Katz. Thus, when a .ZIP file is viewed in a text editor the first two bytes of the file are usually "PK".

I used 7-zip to open your file as the Windows default didn't accept it as a valid file. It contains a manifest.mf file but the content itself seems missing. the file itself has a size of 1.269.519 bytes.

```
HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create("http://deviantsmc.com/binary.txt");
httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
Stream httpResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();

// create and open a FileStream, using calls dispose when done
using(var fs= File.Create(@"c:\temp\bin.7z"))
{
     // Copy all bytes from the responsestream to the filestream
     httpResponseStream.CopyTo(fs);
}
```

Comment: Some antiviruses think "httpResponseStream.CopyTo(fs);" is some attempt to download a malicious file, so they immediately delete the program.

Comment: I am getting this error: "Access to the path 'C\Users\xxx\Desktop' is denied."    Any ideas?

Comment: @k.troy2012 yes, store the file in a folder you have access to and make sure you use a path **AND** a filename. c:\temp\file.zip will work (if you have created a directory named `temp` first). Also use the `@"c:\your\path\and\file.here"` type of string.

Comment: File.Create(@"C:\Users\knhelfen\Desktop\myZipDownload.zip") ... getting the same error.

Comment: Just create a directory somewhere yourself. Write the file in that folder.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write the entire binary data to the local file, instead of encoding it segmentally, you can try this:

```
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)
    WebRequest.Create("http://deviantsmc.com/binary.txt");
    httpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream httpResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
    using (BinaryReader responseReader = new BinaryReader(httpResponseStream.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        byte[] bytes = responseReader.ReadBytes((int)response.ContentLength);
        using (BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("tcontent1.txt")))
        {
            sw.Write(bytes);
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Hope this can help